# What is an internally regulated power generator?

Tags: generator, well-pump

I am looking to add a backup generator to a 10 HP Franklin Electric water well. According to the manual, I can have a significantly reduced size generator if the generator is "internally regulated." Problem is that all the generator vendors I talk to don't know what this means. What power generators are "internally regulated"?

Reference to the backup generator section in the Franklin Electric manual (page 5) is here. https://franklinwater.com/media/123990/Page-5.pdf

Comment: I am not sure what they are trying to say because the field windings are controlled on every generator I have worked on the permanent magnet exciter or slip ring controlled normally used on smaller home generators.  The other type is inverter where dc is generated and electrically converted into AC.

Comment: Are we talking about a single-phase or a three-phase well pump here?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel single-phase pump.

Comment: After hours of researching, I think they may be referring to a generator with an alternator that is internally excited (AREP). https://www.cat.com/en_US/by-industry/electric-power/Articles/White-papers/excitation-selections.html

Comment: So to meet Franklin Electric manual's 'internally excited' definition, "Self-excited" generators would not be good enough; I would need AREP/AUX excitation to fit the 'extra winding' definition. I'm assuming PMG and EBC excitation would also suffice since they are considered better starters than AREP/AUX excitation.